# Is it possible to specify the date/time and price for the entry and exit in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, data-analysis, tradingview-api, trading

does anyone know how to code in Pine to specify the date/time and price for entry and exit? I want to use TW to analyze my actual trades in a strategy, to get data such as MFE, MAE, time to MFE and MAE, time in trade, bars in trade. Thanks.

I've been looking around and also tried some coding myself without any result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `timestamp` for your entries and exits.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)

entry_time = timestamp(2023, 09, 04, 12, 00, 00)
exit_time = timestamp(2023, 09, 05, 18, 00, 00)

if (time == entry_time)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (time == exit_time)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

[image]

You can also use the built-in functions, `strategy.opentrades.entry_time()`, `strategy.closedtrades.entry_time()` and `strategy.closedtrades.exit_time()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if it’s possible to use the timestamp with hours/minutes together with a daily resolution on the chart, or do you need to have the intraday resolution if you want accurate result.

Comment: No, you cannot do intrabar operations when you are on the daily (or higher) timeframes.